# reduction integral formula

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to prove that: ($m\in \mathbb N $ )

$$\int {(ax+b)^{1/2}\over x^{m}} dx = {-(ax+b)^{3/2}\over (m-1)bx^{m-1}}-{(2m-5)a\over(2m-2)b}\int {(ax+b)^{1/2}\over x^{m-1}}dx$$

but with this substitution:

$$ u=(ax+b)^{1/2}; du={adx\over 2(ax+b)^{1/2}} ; dv=x^{-m}dx; v={-1\over (m-1)x^{m-1}}$$ 
I got:

$$\int {(ax+b)^{1/2}\over x^{m}} dx ={-(ax+b)^{1/2}\over (m-1)x^{m-1}}+{a\over 2(m-1)}\int {dx\over x^{m-1}(ax+b)^{1/2}}$$

I would really appreciate your help

Comment: I think the formula you want to prove is wrong. If you move the integral on the right to the left side, and then differentiate both sides, you will have the sum of the integrands on the left and the derivative of the remaining term on the right. When I take that derivative, I don't get the two integrands. Either I've done it wrong or the formula simply isn't true.

Comment: I have checked the formula and it is correct, I got it from this book:mathematical handbook of formulas and tables (schaum series)

Comment: Okay, I guess I just differentiated wrong then, sorry

Comment: @user128422 Just letting you know I have included more details in my answer, in case you already read it.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is right, only unfortunately the $(ax+b)^{1/2}$ winds up in the denominator of the remaining integral, not where it should be for a reduction formula. Better luck is obtained on using that $(ax+b)^{3/2}=(ax+b)\cdot (ax+b)^{1/2}=ax(ax+b)^{1/2}+b(ax+b)^{1/2},$ which on division by $x^m$ gives the relation
$$\frac{(ax+b)^{3/2}}{x^m}=a \cdot \frac{(ax+b)^{1/2}}{x^{m-1}}+b \cdot \frac{(ax+b)^{1/2}}{x^m}. \tag{1}$$
Now when integration by parts is applied to the left of $(1)$ the unintegrated term gives "almost" the first term of the formula you want, only without the extra $b$ in the denominator. But that extra $b$ comes in for the denominator when $(1)$ is solved for $\int (ax+b)^{1/2}/x^m.$ There are two integrals from the right terms on integrating the equation $(1)$, which are the two integrals one wants to relate in the reduction formula. I did the algebra and it works out to give the formula you have.

*Added details:* Let $I_m$ denote $\int (ax+b)^{1/2}/x^m.$ Then on integration, the right side of $(1)$ is $$aI_{m-1}+bI_m.\tag{2}$$ And on integrating the left side of $(1)$ by parts using $u=(ax+b)^{3/2}$ and $dv=1/x^m$ we get 
$$\frac{-(ax+b)^{3/2}}{(m-1)x^{m-1}}+\frac{3a}{2(m-1)}I_{m-1}.\tag{3}$$
At this point the two expressions $(2),(3)$ are equal (up to the added constant of integration), and contain only linear terms in $I_m$ and $I_{m-1}$ and a nonintegrated function, so that one may solve these for $I_m$ in terms of $I_{m-1}$ and the nonintegrated function. The result is the formula mentioned in the post.